# Environment variables(.env) in node js express

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to have a single .env file for all different deployment environments such as development, production , etc.Based on the environment the corresponding environment variables file needs to be loaded.

Comment: It is not clear, what you are trying to achieve. What is the importance of the `.env` format? Why can't you use a `.json` file?

Comment: Hi, env file is different from config file. Env file is hidden and has all configuration such as encrypted password ,file path , etc similar to windows environment variables. It will not be good practice to do this in config file.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. A file doesn't become a config file just because you put the `.json` extension to that. You can have a file called `env.json` and include all passwords etc there. You don't need to include the file in your repository.

Answer (score 48):

Yes. You can use the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) `module` for example:

.env

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

app.js

```
require('dotenv').config()

const db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Install the dotenv module

```
npm install dotenv
```

.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=3000
```

index.js

```
let dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
console.log(dotenv);
```

Output:-

```
{ parsed: { NODE_ENV: 'development', PORT: '3000' } }
```

File strictures:-

```
---| index.js
   | .env
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, not necessarily .env file but a json/js file.

You can make a file like below and require this file with environment -

```
let config = require('./pathToFile/')[process.env.NODE_ENV]
```

Your file -

```
{
"development" : {
    "dbConfig" : {
        "username" : "acaca",
        "password" : "ajbcjdca",
        "port" : "acdc",
         "etc" : "etc"
    },
    "serverConfig" : {
      "host" : "jabcjac.com",
      "port" : "4545",
      "etc" : "etc"
    },
    "AWSConfig" : {
      "accessKey" : "akcakcbk",
      "etc" : "etc"
    }
},
"production" : {
    "dbConfig" : {
        "username" : "acaca",
        "password" : "ajbcjdca",
        "port" : "acdc",
         "etc" : "etc"
    },
    "serverConfig" : {
        "host" : "jabcjac.com",
        "port" : "4545",
        "etc" : "etc"
    },
    "AWSConfig" : {
        "accessKey" : "akcakcbk",
        "etc" : "etc"
    }
},
"test" : {
    "dbConfig" : {
      "username" : "acaca",
      "password" : "ajbcjdca",
      "port" : "acdc",
       "etc" : "etc"
    },
    "serverConfig" : {
      "host" : "jabcjac.com",
      "port" : "4545",
      "etc" : "etc"
    },
    "AWSConfig" : {
      "accessKey" : "akcakcbk",
      "etc" : "etc"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks. But the application requires .env file which has all the environment related configuration which is necessary for the application. The purpose of .env is it varies for each environment. We need to achieve this for .env so that deployment becomes easier and does not require to keep changing the content of file manually.

Comment: @goutham It's generally considered bad practice to use .env files in production. The production environment should always be set explicitly. An incorrectly configured web server can serve the .env file to the public. You also risk accidentally committing it to source control.