# React local workspace setup to connect to REST API server

Tags: reactjs, rest, webpack

Let's say I have a React app and want to connect locally to my local Tomcat server (for ultimately consuming REST endpoints from my React app). I have 2 questions;

> 1. Is there a standard local workspace setup recommended by React to point to our localhost running backend services?
> 2. Is there an easy/configurable setup, where I have both options e.g. switch from connecting to actual backend service TO say using mock
>    endpoint responses on my local i.e. by a simple config change ?

**Note:** I am trying to avoid hardcoding any absolute URLs on my client-side i.e. In my client side code, I would just have the endpoint defined as "mycontext/my/endpoint" and say if my React app is running on say http://localhost, then it should automatically construct the full endpoint as http://localhost/mycontext/my/endpoint

Answer (score 1):

You can [define environment variables](https://reactgo.com/react-environment-variables/), which could include the address of the API server you'd like to use. Then you would simply change that variable any time you wish to hit a different API server (be it localhost or remote).

If you are using Create React App to bootstrap your setup, you can also use [the proxy setting](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) in your package.json.

Comment: Thanks....Is there setup that can be done via ExpressJS (app.listen, app.use, app.get/post, etc) ?

Comment: I don't know much about Express. It's for Node, right? I think the standard answer for environment variables in Node is still [dotenv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48627878/15299500).